# LIMIT não interpreta as variáveis

Tags: php, mysql

Alguém sabe o porque a variáveis não são interpretadas?

Estou passando via ajax com `data:{"inicio=0&fim=2"}` e quando tento retornar para a query não estou conseguindo.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/teste.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: "inicio=0&fim=2",
    beforeSend: '',
    error: '',
    success: function(leitura){
    alert(leitura);             
    }
});
```

teste.php

```
$inicio = $_POST['inicio'];
$fim    = $_POST['fim']; 

$usuarios = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuario LIMIT $inicio,$fim") or die(mysql_error());
```

Já usei o (`int`) porém me retorna `0`;

Mysql 5.7

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78325/discussion-on-question-by-lucas-barbosa-limit-nao-interpreta-as-variaveis)

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você esta fazendo leitura no seu Banco de Dados, então utilize o método "GET". Veja um pouco sobre requisições http:

[Requisições HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)

Você deve estar tentando fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
<script>                                         
   $(document).ready(function(){                                        
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'www.seusite.com/teste.php?inicio=0&fim=2',
            success: function(data)
            {
              $("#IdDeUmaDiv").append(data);
            }
             });                                                          
         });                                                        
</script>

<div id="IdDeUmaDiv"></div>
```

Você consegue fazer isso de um modo mais fácil! Utilize o load do jquery! Crie uma pagina simples para resultados e faça apenas um load na div quando precisar! Veja como e simples:

```
<a onclick="$('#IdDeUmaDiv').load('url');">Buscar</a>
```

Você pode passar os parametros pela url e pegar no arquivo utilizando o $_GET["nomedoparametro"];

Seu SQL ta errado! Veja um pouco como funciona intervalos de busca! Não se utiliza "Limit" para isso Utilioza-se o BETWEEN! Veja com se faz nesse Link:

[BETEWEEN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

Comment: Perfeito!!! Obrigado Cristy.